# How to get the index value in an awk array

Tags: awk

I have this data where $1,$2 are from a different source from $3,$4,..,$8. $1,$3 are similar, only not sorted:-

```
code :name :     code: type <br/>
0555:GeoLocate:2754:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:5:<br/>
930:topup:6463:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:5:<br/> 
234:ota:3744:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0:<br/>
2000:FA_ussd:744:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0:<br/>
1450:IMPT:5434:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0: <br/>
1450:IMPT:930:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0:<br/>
5551:adt:1450:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:10:<br/>
```

I need to organise them in this format:-

1450 IMPT GSM MT SMS Charge 10

Using:-

```
BEGIN{
FS=":";
}
{
a[$1]++;
for (x in a){
if($3 == x){
b[$2]++;
print x,b[a[x]],$4,$5,$6,$7,$8;
}
}
}
```

But when I run this,

```
$ awk -f awkscript.awk sampleData
```

output for b[a[x]] is empty:

1450   GSM MT SMS Charge 10 
930   GSM MT SMS Charge 0
how can I get the index for IMPT in the array b since it has the same index as x in a?

Comment: This looks like it could be a nice problem, but I'm afraid people might be feeling like they have to work too hard to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Do I understand right that for each line you want to print `$3 <something> $4 $5 $6 $7 $8`, where `<something>` is the $2 associated with $1 from a different line where that $1 is the same as the $3 of the line being printed? (In other words, a self-join on the first and third fields)

Comment: Post expected output.

Comment: yes exactly, $1 and $2 are from a different data source, $3-$8 from another. I hoped to get the $3 <name of code> $4 $5 $6 ...

Comment: Why do we care what source the fields are from? Does it make any kind of functional difference to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly (see my comment to the original question), you can try something like:

```
bash-3.2$ cat sample.data
0555:GeoLocate:2754:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:5:<br/>
930:topup:6463:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:5:<br/> 
234:ota:3744:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0:<br/>
2000:FA_ussd:744:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0:<br/>
1450:IMPT:5434:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0: <br/>
1450:IMPT:930:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:0:<br/>
5551:adt:1450:GSM:MT:SMS:Charge:10:<br/>


bash-3.2$ awk -F: 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } { print $3, a[$3]?a[$3]:"(not found)", $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 }' sample.data sample.data
2754 (not found) GSM MT SMS Charge 5
6463 (not found) GSM MT SMS Charge 5
3744 (not found) GSM MT SMS Charge 0
744 (not found) GSM MT SMS Charge 0
5434 (not found) GSM MT SMS Charge 0
930 topup GSM MT SMS Charge 0
1450 IMPT GSM MT SMS Charge 10
```

Note that we give the same sample.data file twice on the command line. The first pass builds the index and the second pass prints the output using that index. Also there's the question of what to do if the $3 doesn't occur as $1 anywhere in the file. Here it just prints "(not found)" in that case.

**EDIT**

To avoid the "not found"s you can use this variation of the above awk:

```
bash-3.2$ awk -F: 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } { if (a[$3]) print $3, a[$3], $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 }' sample.data sample.data
930 topup GSM MT SMS Charge 0
1450 IMPT GSM MT SMS Charge 10
```

Comment: Hi, This solved my problem! I pipped awk '{if ($2!="(not"){print $0;}}' to remove the "(not found)". Thanks!

Comment: Great! I've edited the answer with an alternative for avoiding the "not founds" without an extra awk.